# Can I use React.js for native mobile apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, difference

Is it possible to develop native mobile apps with React.js or do I need explicitly React Native for mobile apps? What are the differences between react.js and react native?

Answer (score 5):

**React**

> The definition is "JavaScript (**JavaScript**)Library for creating the
>   user interface (UI).

In short, it is designed to solve the problem of receiving code from the server and re-rendering the page when an event is requested. Because it's not a framework, it's a library, and I don't have to change all the code just because I'm using it. You can just take it and use it when you need it.

React is a library for creating a "user interface."

This means that `MVC` is focused only on **VIEW**. It is said to be both good and bad. Because it is a library for View only, functions other than View should be implemented or implemented directly.

Also, **IE8** and below are not supported.

**React-native**

> React Native is a library that helps you create a **native mobile app**.

Create real-world mobile apps that are indistinguishable from apps created using `Objective-C`, `Java`, or `Swift`. **React Native** uses the same basic UI building block as regular `iOS` and `Android` apps. Bringing these building blocks together using JavaScript and `React`. (**React Native** separates the `JavaScript` code and native code into separate threads, making communication between the two asynchronous, so there is no slowing down.)
Also that we can reduce the compilation time.
You don't have to do an app made with **React native**. Instead of recompiling, the app can be reloaded immediately. If you use a refresh, you can run a new code while maintaining your app status.

The downside is to use APIs for each platform. And for apps with a lot of animation, the performance may fall a little bit with **React native**.

They say business logic can slow down even if it's complicated, and there's a lot of communication between the `native view` <-> `JavaScript` logic.

You can't create apps with **React**, but you can create the Web with **React native**. See [this link](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) for more information.

Comment: @user2774480 If my answer was helpful, would you check the 'V' and the arrows to select the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**React** is a Javascript library responsible for building a hierarchy of UI components

or 
**React Native** is a framework for building native applications using JavaScript. React Native compiles to native app components

**Reactjs** is used for web and desktop apps
and **React native for mobile development